# How can I convert image on the hard disk png to be transparent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

```
private void ConvertImagestoTransparent(string filename)
{
    var image = new Bitmap(filename, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 135, 135);
    }
}
```

This give me error the new Bitmap is not getting filename:

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat' to 'bool'

Also not getting Bitmap.

In the constructor:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\images\");
Files = d.GetFiles("*.png");
```

Is it possible to convert the png images to transparent ? Will it lost quality ?

Comment: "Will it lost quality?" - If you load a lossy format and save a lossy format then yes, it will lose quality. If you load a lossless format and save a lossy format, then yes, it will lose quality. If you save as a lossless format then your quality will remain the same (though your file size might increase). See this article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression

Comment: The error is because of using wrong constructor parameters. What's your goal? Share an input image and an output desired image or say what do you mean by converting png to transparent?

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap` constructor you're using is only for **loading** existing images. If you want to create one, then you need to use [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3z132tat(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var image = new Bitmap(theWidth, theHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Then, you can save your image to a file like this:

```
image.Save(filename);
```

For your 2nd question, what do you mean by "convert the png images to transparent"? Do you want to remove the background color from the images?